# Match a specific sequence or everything else with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Been trying to come up with a regex in JS that could split user input like :

```
"Hi{user,10,default} {foo,10,bar} Hello"
```

into:

```
["Hi","{user,10,default} ","{foo,10,bar} ","Hello"]
```

So far i achieved to split these strings with `({.+?,(?:.+?){2}})|([\w\d\s]+)` but the second capturing group is too exclusive, as I want every character to be matched in this group. Tried `(.+?)` but of course it fails...

Ideas fellow regex gurus?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
"Hi{user,10,default} {foo,10,bar} Hello".split(/(\{.*?\})/)
```

And you will get this

```
["Hi", "{user,10,default}", " ", "{foo,10,bar}", " Hello"]
```

Note: `{.*?}`. The question mark here ('?') stops at fist match of '}'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex I came up with:

```
(:?[^\{])+|(:?\{.+?\})
```

Like the one above, it includes that space as a match.

Comment: It's almost what I am looking for, but I want to enforce the 3 args rule between the curly braces, i.e. if there is `"Hi {simple} {user,10,default}"`, I am expecting `["Hi {simple}", {user,10,default}"]` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Beeing no JavaScript expert, I would suggest the following:

- get all positive matches using `({[^},]*,[^},]*,[^},]*?})`
- remove all positive matches from the original string
- split up the remaining string

Allthough, this might get tricky if you need the resulting values in order.