# How can I capture "everything else" that I haven't already matched in a Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a simple script parser in Javascript, and for the tokenizing part of the lexer I wanted to use Regex.

There are certain tokens I'm looking for, like (*including the quotes*):

- "last-name"
- "first-name"
- "staff-id"

I also look for horizontal whitespace and vertical whitespace.

Finally, I look for whatever else is not matched by those tokens and white spaces.

The Regex would look something like:

```
("last-name"|"first-name"|"staff-id")|([\t ]+)|([\r\n]+)|(.+?)
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^
 tokens                                whitespace         catch-all
```

But I'm having a problem with the "catch-all" at the end: `(.+?)` The resulting capture for this last part is one character each.

What I wanted to do was capture everything together in that catch-all instead of one character at a time. I've Googled around and looked at stackoverflow answers, like the following:

- [Match a specific sequence or everything else with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3473634/8685342)
- [How do I match everything except matched value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35682802/8685342)

One solution I can do is concatenate all the "catch-all" results, one character at a time. For this particular project, that's fine, but for another one I'd rather have a Regex solution that could capture everything else in a "catch-all", if that's even possible.

So how can I capture "everything else" that I haven't already matched in a Regex?

Comment: @anubhava You're right, that would catch everything, but for the lexer the order of the captures are important, and .replace() would lose this order. Is there a sequence you suggest to use .replace() that would maintain order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do `string.split(/("last-name"|"first-name"|"staff-id")|([\t ]+)|([\r\n]+)/g)` so you have a sequence of `[catch-all, ...groups, catch-all, ...]` starting and ending with a catch-all. Although it can be an empty string.

```js
const test = `name "last-name"\n"first-name" Lucy`.split(/("last-name"|"first-name"|"staff-id")|([\t ]+)|([\r\n]+)/g);


for (let i = 0; i < test.length;) {
  if (i & 1) {
    console.log("match", {
      "tokens": test[i],
      "[\\t ]+": test[i + 1],
      "[\\r\\n]+": test[i + 2],
    });
    i += 3
  } else {
    console.log({
      "rest": test[i],
    });
    ++i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Huh, that's really neat and simple! I think this coupled with @anubhava's comment nicely answers the question. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, actually this solves the entire problem on its own. I didn't realize .split() inserted captured regular expression values (including undefined) into the resultant array, and that's what you were showing. This function is great!